Experimental status/test possibilities for baryon number conservation in LHC?
Violation of baryon number is hypothesized e.g. for baryogenesis (more matter than antimatter from Big Bang) or Hawking radiation (baryons -> black hole -> massless radiation) - quite extreme conditions.
In contrast, unsuccessful search for proton decay is mainly focused on room temperature water - maybe we just need more extreme conditions? Like centers of neutron stars especially those producing orders of magnitude more energy than expected, e.g. X82 X-2: https://www.space.com/bizare-object-10-times-brighter-than-sun
More accessibly in high energy experiments like LHC - is there any experimental evidence pro/against violation of baryon number from LHC? If not, is it in reach to confirm or deny possibility of its violation?
For example here is a fresh from ALICE: https://cerncourier.com/a/balancing-matter-and-antimatter-in-pb-pb-collisions/ writing:

for every 1000 produced protons, approximately 986 ± 6 antiprotons are produced

But to check baryon number conservation we would also need to include other baryons, and subtract from initial Pb-Pb.

the present standard model of particle physics is an encapsulation of data and observation  of particle physics , from where the SU3xSu2Xu1 group symmetry emerged . This is absolutely dependent on the axiomatic assumption of baryon number conservation.All interactions and decays measured up to now do not violate it at all, afaik.

@annav, so how could more baryons than antibaryons be created in Big Bang? How could black holes evaporate through massless radiation? How could e.g. X82 X-2 get orders of magnitude higher power than explainable? As scientists we shouldn't assume it, only try to ask nature: test it - and LHC seems a natural place for that. Couldn't they e.g. calculate statistics like in this recent ALICE article to confirm or deny that the number of baryons before and after collisions is the same? (at least statistically)

I cannot think of a way , but that does not mean much. I expect that if there were significant violations, the predictions of the standard model that depend on baryon number conservation would be falsified, so it will be, if it exists, a small effect , not enough for cosmological models.

@annav The mentioned ALICE article says: "for every 1000 produced protons, approximately 986 ± 6 antiprotons are produced" - sure the differences would be tiny, but with large enough statistics should be verifiable (?)

I guess I am trying to say that iff a cosmological theory can come up with :  at the beginning of time plasma  had a high probability of evolving without antibaryons to describe the universe we live in, even if the standard model limits  to small values of  baryon violation, I expect the scientific community of elementary particles will come up with an experiment to test baryon violation. At present there is no incentive.

I am trying to say that baryon violation in elementary particle interactions, even if there,  is experimentally too small to add up to the baryon violation needed to describe the evolution to the  present universe. At the same time it is too small to affect the standard model which is the gauge that is used for deciding  particle experiments.

Maybe it was Big Bounce with the same baryon number before ... but we don't know, and the duty of scientists is to search for evidence to try to answer such questions. Not finding proton decay in room temperature water, it might just require conditions closer to where it is hypothesized: baryogenesis and Hawking radiation - on Earth only colliders get close to such conditions. If it is technically possible (?), how to convince them to try to systematically analyze such statistics - maybe to improve evidence that baryon number is indeed ultimately conserved (or not)?

At present particle physicists depend on the fact that the standard model fits almost all data , and experiment  at the limits to find contradictions and new physics. Baryon violation with the present SM is very improbable within the measurement possibilities of  LHC instrumentation. Lets say it is a small effect. It is not attractive enough to go to the expense of an experiment with the large statistics needed to experimentally detect it, if it is there. Now if a cosmological theory comes up with a method of how , a small elementary particle interaction effect can be amplified by the

plasma existing at the beginning to give the large violation observed, then it will become interesting to design an experiment and see if there is baryon violation or not.

If baryon number is ultimately conserved, then more baryons than antibaryons could not be produced in Big Bang - requiring e.g. cyclic model, baryon number surviving Big Bounces. That is interesting hypothesis, but requiring more evidence to be certain - and nearly only LHC approaches such conditions: could evaluate its probability by analyzing large statistics.

The paper whose press release you cite looks at a number of baryons and other hadrons:

In this Letter, we report the most precise estimation to date of $μ_B$ and $μ_Q$ obtained from a set of antiparticle-to-particle yield ratios. The analyzed species are charged pions, protons, $Ω^−$ baryons, and light (hyper)nuclei. (Anti)protons are the most abundantly produced (anti)baryons at midrapidity (≈ 35 and ≈ 2 protons on average in central and peripheral Pb–Pb collisions, respectively [45]). Consequently, the antiproton-to-proton yield ratio can probe the antibaryon-to-baryon imbalance [42, 46] with high precision. On the other hand, the sensitivity to baryon asymmetry is enhanced when light (hyper)nuclei are included because of their larger baryon content. In this work, $\rm ^3He$, its isobar $\rm ^3H$, and hypertriton $\rm ^3_ΛH$, which is a bound state of a proton, a neutron, and a Λ, along with their antimatter counterparts, are considered$^1$. The ratio of oppositely charged pions provides a precise constraint on the imbalance of electric charge, as the yield ratio depends predominantly on $μ_Q$. Finally, the dependence of antimatter-to-matter ratios on strangeness is probed with (anti)$Ω^−$ baryons, which, unlike (anti)Λ and (anti)$Ξ^−$, have negligible contamination coming from heavier hadron decays.

The number headlined in the press release, a proton-antiproton asymmetry of  $0.986±0.006$, is one of of about thirty such ratios reported in Figure A.1 of the paper.  I have only skimmed the paper, rather than trying to reproduce the analysis, but they report the "baryon chemical potential $\mu_B$," which is a measure of baryon-number nonconservation in the context of a statistical ensemble of particles and antiparticles, to be "compatible with zero within $1.6\sigma$." This is a result you would expect in somewhat more than one in twenty experiments if the actual baryon number violation were zero, just due to statistical fluctuations.
You contrast with cold proton decay experiments, but you may not have done the arithmetic.  All of the processes in the Standard Model are happening all of the time, because our universe only has one vacuum state, and the Standard Model describes its symmetries and their particle-like properties.  There are frequently situations where you can neglect some weak or rare process, but you can never turn these processes off.  Compare with air resistance, which we frequently have intro-physics students ignore, whether that ignoring is appropriate or not.  We usually don't teach the rule of thumb that air resistance becomes important when the mass of displaced air becomes comparable to the mass of the object that's moving.  This is why you can ignore air resistance if you're juggling golf balls but not if you're playing golf; this is why you can say that interplanetary space is a vacuum, but also talk about the hydrodynamics of the solar wind and its effect on interplanetary dust.
The LHC can excite the vacuum to temperatures where we might hope to see signs of baryon-number violation in $10^{20\text{-ish}}$ interactions.  (I don't actually know the size of the LHC dataset. The part-per-billion measurements that I've done needed $10^{19\text{-ish}}$ interactions to get the statistical noise small enough to be interesting; I remember suddenly realizing that I was analyzing the behavior of an entire microgram of free neutrons.)  The proton-decay experiment at Super-Kamiokande looked at $10^{30\text{-ish}}$ protons for several years, setting a lower limit on baryon-number-violating decays at zero temperature somewhere above $10^{33}$ years.  I don't know which result is more stringent, but I'm pretty sure it's the cold protons.


The most important thing to keep in mind is that the LHC cannot directly check baryon conservation because of limited kinematic coverage of the detectors (many fragments fly down the beam pipe), and the difficulty in detecting neutral baryons (such as neutrons). The closest thing one can do is look for specific baryon number violating decays that involve distinct final states.

The Alice experiment measures a small net-proton excess at central rapidity (longitudinal momentum), where the detector has coverage. This is not surprising -- a bigger excess was observed at RHIC. The mechanism is related to the fact that most baryons at central rapidity are produced by hadronization of pair produced quarks and anti-quarks, but some are produced by stopping of baryons in the original nuclei (which obviously have an excess of baryons over anti-baryons). The effect is bigger at lower energy (RHIC), because the nuclei have smaller energy, and projectile baryons are easier to stop.

There is a mechanism for baryon number violation in the standard model (related to electroweak instantons, see for example this question). This rate is unobservably small under ordinary conditions, but at some point there were suggestions that the rate grows with energy, and that the effect could be observable at the LHC (see, e.g. Arnold and Mattis). The idea was that these events would be unusual in many ways (democratic in quark and lepton flavor, many W's produced, most at central rapidity), so that events can be detected without complete kinematic coverage. This is now considered extremely unlikely.

I think you can safely ignore the X-82 story (this is about details of the accretion mechanism in neutron stars).



Thank you for explanation. Regarding 4.: assuming baryon number violation is allowed in baryognesis, Hawking radiation, the centers of neutron stars are quite close to these conditions - how could we confirm or deny baryon violation there? "Producing more energy than explainable without it" would be a clear evidence, but question is where is this boundary? M82 X-2 is said to "break the laws of physics" for these reasons ( https://explorersweb.com/neutron-star-breaks-laws-of-physics/ ) - why not include in considerations hypothesis that at least part of this energy comes from baryon decay?

We should of course keep an open mind, but there are many constraints when it comes to possible baryon number violation. 1) Neutron stars are stable for millions of years. 2) Isolated (non-accreting) neutron stars are cooling, not heating. 3) The conditions are only moderately more dense than ordinary nuclei -- you have to find a mechanism that allows baryon number violation in the cores of neutron stars, but Pb nuclei are stable.

Having said this, people are looking at exotic options, eg baryon number violating neutron decay, see here https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08282

I would expect it especially in the centers of neutron stars just before collapse to the black hole - reaching conditions for Hawking radiation destroying baryons, and maybe slowing down the collapse by such energy release. If black hole horizon starts it the center (seems there are different hypotheses), in theory it would need reaching infinite matter density in such point - exceeding any finite threshold for proton decay. Balancing at the edge of such collapse might explain ultraluminous sources like M82 X-2 (?)

Again, one should keep an open mind, but we have see at least one conventional neutron star merger with the formation of a black hole  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW170817. The LIGO signature is consistent with the inspiral, merger and collapse of two ~1.5 M(solar) neutron stars, and the optical counter part is consistent with the light emitted by a few tens of solar masses of nucleosynthetic material (radioactive elements created in the merger) ejected from the accretion disk. No evidence for anything exotic.

If baryon number violation would happen in the centers of neutron star short before collapse into black hole, the observational consequence would be higher energy and slower collapse ... I don't think it could be confirmed or denied by LIGO (?), rather by exceeding maximal power allowed without it.

Well, if the time scale for collapse does not match predictions from general relativistic hydro plus standard equations of state then LIGO will tell us that (although right now the last stage, the ringdown of the proto-BH is outside the LIGO frequency range. This will soon change). Also, if there is anything in the associated gamma ray burst or long term light curve that cannot be attributed to the accretion disk or radioactive decays the observation will tell us that, too. Right now it all looks like conventional physics.

LHC events are too messy with too many missed or misidentified particles for direct baryon and anti-baryon counting to be an effective method to look for Baryon Number Violation (BNV), but limits can be set by using charged leptons to tag the baryon number in top quark production and decay.   The CMS Collaboration has set limits as small as $10^{-8}$ for the fraction of top quark decays that violate baryon number conservation.
Theoretical Background
For Grand Unified Theories where baryon number violation is mediated by a boson with (very large) mass $M_{BNV}$, the higher energy of the LHC is grossly insufficient to compete with proton decay experiments.  BNV production and decay rates would be
$$\sigma_{BNV}\sim \hbar^2 c^2 \frac{s}{M_{BNV}^4}\qquad \mathrm{and} \qquad \tau_{BNV}\sim \hbar \frac{M_{BNV}^4}{Q^5}$$
where $Q$ is the decay energy, $s$ is the centre-of-mass energy squared, $\hbar$ is the reduced Planck constant, and $c$ is the speed of light.
The existing lower bound on the proton lifetime of $\tau_p > 9\times10^{29}$ years for $Q\sim m_p$ implies that at the LHC ($\sqrt{s}\sim14$ TeV)
$$\sigma_{BNV}<\frac{\hbar^3 c^2 s}{\tau_p m_p^5}\sim 10^{-39}\,\mathrm{fb}$$
To see even one such event would take many, many orders of magnitude longer than the age of the universe.
What is relevant at the LHC is baryon number violation via Standard Model sphaleron/instanton tunnelling between different vacuum states. Such processes are exponentially suppressed at low temperatures but might be observable at the LHC if the potential barrier separating the vacua is not too much above the Electroweak Scale. (The processes are non-perturbative and hence hard to calculate.)
More theoretical details can, for example, be found in:

"Proton Lifetime and Baryon Number Violating Signatures at the LHC in Gauge Extended Models" (2005)
"Baryon number violation at the LHC: the top option" (2012)

CMS Experimental Limits
The CMS limits come from searching for BNV production processes such as $ud\rightarrow \bar{t}e^+$ or BNV violating decays  such as $t\rightarrow b\mu^+\nu_\mu$ or $\bar{t}\rightarrow \bar{b}e^-\bar{\nu}_e$. Most theoretical models for baryon number (B) violation also violate lepton number (L), but conserve B-L, so CMS uses the sign of the charged lepton in semileptonic decays to distinguish $t$ and $\bar{t}$ quarks.  These CMS top BNV limits are

$\lt 0.15\%$, from "Search for baryon number violation in top-quark decays" (2014).
from $\lesssim 10^{-8}$ for $t\rightarrow ud (e/\mu)$ to  $\lesssim 10^{-6}$ for $t\rightarrow bc (e/\mu)$, from "Search for baryon number violation in top quark production and decay using proton-proton collisions at √s = 13 TeV" (2024).

The following CMS paper does not look directly for baryon number violation, but gives a limit on sphaleron production based on event topology.

Sphaleron limit $\lt 2.1\%$, "Search for black holes and sphalerons in high-multiplicity final states in proton-proton collisions at s√= 13 TeV" (2018).

In principle, limits on top quark BNV production and decays without lepton number violation could be set by searching for processes such as $ud\rightarrow \bar{t}\bar{b}\bar{c}c$ or $t\rightarrow \bar{b}\bar{c}\bar{b}\bar{c}c$, but identifying such events would be a daunting challenge.
